# Are these paper figures actually Origami?

Tags: merchandise, hyperdimension-neptunia

So in my Collectors Edition for *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth3* it came with a sheet which can be made into this paper figure:

[image: Purple Heart paper figure]

I have also seen similar things on eBay of the Puella Magi from *Puella Magi Madoka Magica*.

Are these figures Origami, or is there a different name for them which one could use for finding similar products?

Comment: The current most widely adopted definition of origami *usually* implies (amongst others): one sheet of paper, no cuts, no glue. So... no (but it might have qualified a few decades years ago, and might again in the future). There is also kirigami, which deals with paper cutting...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think they can be considered [Papercraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_model).
Also called Pepakura, from "pepa kurafuto", I guess.

If you search google for pepakura models, you can find sites with lots of designs to print and assemble.

Since you will need scissors and most times, glue, they are not considered origami.

Comment: [Danbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danbo_(character)) is also papercraft ?